# Screenshot quality on Google Play store via app - getting compressed, blurry and ruined

Tags: android, image, image-processing, google-play, app-store

When viewing the screenshots for an app via the Google Play app, the screenshots displayed are compressed and low quality. When viewing the Play app store page via a desktop web browser, they're full quality.

I've tried several suggestions, including:
- Trying JPEG's and PNG's
- Using images with lower dimensions and higher dimensions
- Compressing the images myself to reduce their file size

None of these really make a difference, and Google still seems to compress them pretty heavily (i.e. if I compress them myself, Google just compresses them more to make them even worse). There are a couple people who have made similar complaints online without a solution that seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution?

Comment: I thought it's only on my device. They should have mentioned it on the docs.