# Google Play screenshots and images get pixelated/blurry

Tags: image, google-play

Whenever I upload images to Google Play, they get really pixelated and blurry. It only happens when I view the images via the Google Play mobile Application, in the browser everything looks fine. How can i solve the problem? I'm having exactly the same issue as described here: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755334/screenshot-quality-on-google-play-store-via-app-getting-compressed-blurry-and)
I've tried uploading the images as png, jpg and compressing them but nothing has worked yet. I've added an example screenshot of what the images look like on google play.[awful image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06QvQ.png)
Thank You!

Comment: can you screenshot, there image?
maybe your mobile application isn't progressive web app when you create

Comment: I've added an example screenshot to the post so you can see the issue.